# How to check if a user is younger than 13 with Postgres check constraint?

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can I check if a user is older than 13 with a Postgres check constraint?

I've tried:

```
birthday::date < (birthday::date - '13 years'::interval)
```

And for some reason it won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check against the current date:

```
birthday::date < (now() - '13 years'::interval)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the birthdate with current date like this:

```
check (birthday + '13 years'::interval <= current_date)
```